# ifconfig shows multiple network interfaces

Tags: networking, macos, command-line, network-interface, ifconfig

When I run `ifconfig`on my Macbook air 2018 with MacOS Mojave 10.14.6 I get this:

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=1203<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TXSTATUS,SW_TIMESTAMP>
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
XHC20: flags=0<> mtu 0
XHC0: flags=0<> mtu 0
VHC128: flags=0<> mtu 0
en3: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx 
    inet6 xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx%en3 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x7 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (100baseTX <full-duplex>)
    status: active
ap1: flags=8802<BROADCAST,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx 
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx 
    inet6 xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x9 
    inet xxx.xxx.x.x netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
p2p0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
    ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx 
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
awdl0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1484
    ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx 
    inet6 xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx%awdl0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xb 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
en1: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en2: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x2
    member: en1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 12 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 13 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
utun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 2000
    inet6 xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx%utun0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xf 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
ipsec0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1400
    inet xx.x.x.xxx --> xx.x.x.xxx netmask 0xff000000
```

I'm not very good at networking stuff but this seems strange to me due to the fact that I never saw this many network interfaces on my old macbook air.

**Question: Is this normal or could this be something bad? What can I do about it if it is something bad?**

All the "x"s were not there originally, I changed the addresses to them instead

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That looks pretty normal.

- **lo0** is the loopback virtual interface.
- **en0** is your built-in Wi-Fi.
- **en1** and **en2** are your Thunderbolt ports. macOS supports IP over Thunderbolt this way.
- **bridge0** is a virtual interface that bridges your two IP over Thunderbolt interfaces together.
- **en3** is likely an external Ethernet dongle in your scenario.
- **awdl0** is Apple Wireless Direct Link. It's an Apple-proprietary, incompatible equivalent to Wi-Fi Aware or Wi-Fi Direct. It's how AirDrop and AirPlay and Handoff and a few other things work.
- **p2p0** Is like an earlier version of AWDL. When AirDrop first came out and was Mac-only, it used this. iOS never used this and used AWDL instead. Now both platforms prefer AWDL but the older mac-only Apple Peer to Peer wireless protocol still exists for backwards compatibility with older Macs running ancient versions of macOS.
- **utun0** is a tunnel virtual interface used for VPN connections.
- **ipsec0** is also a VPN-related virtual interface.
- **gif0** is a virtual "generic interface" used for certain IPv6-in-IPv4 tunneling situations.
- **stf0** is a virtual interface for an obsolete IPv4/IPv6 transition mechanism known as 6to4 that is still in use by a few people.
- The ***HC*** interfaces are for using a packet sniffer to capture USB traffic instead of network traffic.

Please note that the exact meanings of en0-enX vary from model to model. The lowest numbers go to built-in Ethernet ports first (in any exist) then to built-in Wi-Fi, then to built-in Thunderbolt ports, if any. After that comes add-on Ethernet-like interfaces (such as USB Ethernet dongles, Thunderbolt Ethernet dongles, and USB Wi-Fi dongles) in the order they were seen by the system.

Comment: I am connected to a vpn so that makes sense. Regarding en3, I don't have any external devices connected such as an Ethernet dongle or USB, is it weird that it still shows up or could it be any of my thunderbolt ports even though nothing is connected to them? Regarding the HC interfaces, is this something bad or is it normal too? I've never connected a USB to my computer before

Comment: I can't find info about the following interface `veth8cc4233`